# How to eliminate 'No value accessor for form control' in template-drive Angular forms

Tags: angular

I'm using the official published documentation sample code at  https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModelGroup

though I find I still have the issue WITHOUT USING the ngModelGroup directive

**form.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
 selector: 'example-app',

template: `
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
  <p *ngIf="nameCtrl.invalid">Name is invalid.</p>

  <div ngModelGroup="name" #nameCtrl="ngModelGroup">
    <input name="first" [ngModel]="name.first" minlength="2">
    <input name="last" [ngModel]="name.last" required>
  </div>

  <input name="email" ngModel> 
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<button (click)="setValue()">Set value</button>
`,
})
export class FormComponent {
name = {first: 'Nancy', last: 'Drew'};

onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
console.log(f.value);  // {name: {first: 'Nancy', last: 'Drew'}, email: ''}
console.log(f.valid);  // true
}

setValue() { this.name = {first: 'Bess', last: 'Marvin'}; }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm, NgModelGroup, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormComponent } from './form/form.component';


@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
FormComponent,
NgForm,NgModelGroup,NgModel

],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**
`<example-app></example-app>`

and in Console receiving this error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form
>   control with path: 'name -> first' Error: No value accessor for form
>   control with path: 'name -> first'
>       at _throwError (forms.es5.js:1918)
>       at setUpControl (forms.es5.js:1828)
>       at forms.es5.js:3955
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:392)
>       at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:3890)
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:391)
>       at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:142)
>       at zone.js:844
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:425)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
>       at _throwError (forms.es5.js:1918)
>       at setUpControl (forms.es5.js:1828)
>       at forms.es5.js:3955
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:392)
>       at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:3890)
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:391)
>       at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:142)
>       at zone.js:844
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:425)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
>       at zone.js:847
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:425)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:424)
>       at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
>       at

@angular/cli: 1.3.2

node: 6.11.0

os: win32 x64

@angular/animations: 4.3.6

@angular/common: 4.3.6

@angular/compiler: 4.3.6

@angular/core: 4.3.6

@angular/forms: 4.3.6

@angular/http: 4.3.6

@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.6

@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.6

@angular/router: 4.3.6

@angular/cli: 1.3.2

@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.6

@angular/language-service: 4.3.6

Comment: I just copied the code from the referenced documentation and pasted it into a Plunker and it seems to work fine. The plunker is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZnjOGq9U1vZmX3XndHQI?p=preview Is it possible the error is somewhere else in the code? Do you have the `ngModule` updated for this component and for the `FormsModule`?

Comment: @DeborahK I've updated the question with all relevant files. The HTML you put in plunker is totally different than what my compiler is producing. Your HTML has no Javascript bundles. -thx

Comment: I don't understand? I am just using Plunker's standard Angular template and then pasting in the code from the docs as you said you used?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use NgForm, NgModel and other such stuff in your custom component then you'll need to import FormsModule into the NgModule which declares your component. BTW, your link provides module name (FormsModule) which you need to import. Also, you don't need to declare directives NgForm, NgModelGroup and NgModel separately since they're already declared in the FormsModule.

So, your module should look something like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormComponent } from './form/form.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        FormComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule // <-- this is what you need to do
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Explanation of this exact error**

In fact, the error is pretty much self-explanatory. You need to provide something that implements ControlValueAccessor interface ([DefaultValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/DefaultValueAccessor) would be used in your particular case), because NgModel which you put on the input **requires** it. Class that implements ControlValueAccessor is what actually puts value in the DOM element and handles user input from it. This is an angular's abstraction of DOM user input elements of different types - radio buttons, checkboxes, text inputs, and selects, to name a few. So, since you have not given anything that implements this interface (and provides said implementation using NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR token), angular injector complains that it cannot instantiate NgModel for this reason. But if you import FormsModule then you will get all this stuff at once since this module provides several value accessors out of the box with no additional declarations.

Comment: Yes, this worked.thank you very much. Don't know why this compiled if there was no interface implemented. Also, one would benefit if the console logs actually were self-explanatory as you say.nowhere mentions ControlValueAccesor not implemented. It says no 'value accessor' for form.

Comment: @DeborahK

Deborah, all my Angular index.html files have this format in the script tag
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>

Comment: @arod, just for clarity - lack of implementation of this interface is not what triggering this error. Lack of provider of NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR is what triggers it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding FormsModule to the imports array in app.module.ts solved this:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule // <-- this is what you need to do
],
```